# Mount Google Drive without root or FUSE

Tags: linux, mount, google-drive

I've got a plan on a shared hosting server that doesn't allow me to use root or install a FUSE module.

I'm aware of the existence of Googles own `drive` tool, and `rclone`, but they both offer barebones push/pull without FUSE.

Is there any other way I can mount my Google Drive?

Comment: Try 4.17 kernel. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Unprivileged-FUSE-Almost

Comment: I doubt I'll be able to convince the owner to do that, think he uses some sort of custom kernel for it.